# Any way to speed up numpy.cumsum()

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a project where I calculate the cumulative sum of many large arrays. At 2 seconds on a server of mine this step is a large bottleneck. Is there any way I can speed it up?
Note these arrays represent temperature measurements. So they are floating point values that can be both negative or positive. While I have more cores available I'm already using parallel processing elsewhere, so that would not speed things up in this case.

```
import numpy as np
import time

forcing = np.random.rand(380*1400*620).reshape((380,1400,620))

start = time.time()
forcing.cumsum(axis=0)
np_time = time.time() - start
print(np_time)
2.085033416748047
```

Comment: Short bench reveals that NumPy is only using 1-core for me. Thus, you could at least achieve more performance by just slicing the array and applying map reduce over the slices with all cores of your system.

Comment: Can you rearrange your array so that it is the *last* axis that is being summed?  This should improve the CPU's use of its cache.  My timing improved, from about 2.5 seconds to 1.9 seconds.  Not a huge gain, but it helps.

Comment: @daniel451 I'm already using multiple cores elsewhere, so adding that here wouldn't improve things for me.

Comment: Any more details that you can give on these arrays?  `cumsum` is probably as optimized as it can be.  But depending on what you can change about the arrays there may be some things that could speed up calculations considerably.  @WarrenWeckesser pointed out one.  My quick profiling also shows that using a `float32` datatype gives a small improvement over the default `float64`.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Thanks! that improves things for me by a similar amount. But unfortunately using swapaxes to get arrange things takes it back to the original ~2 seconds.

Comment: @user2699 They're actually just integers. I tried using `as.type(np.int32)`, which didn't help. But `as.type(np.float32)` does improve it ~20-30%

Comment: is [GPU](http://stsievert.com/blog/2016/07/01/numpy-gpu/) hardware available?

Comment: @Shawn: Warren's suggestion would be contingent on being able to keep the data swapped; if you can keep things in the "swapped" form (which would involve changing all other uses of the array unfortunately), you can avoid the swapping overhead. Also, I'll note that the difference between floating point and integer does matter here a bit. With a similar test case where `forcing` is made with `np.random.randint(0, 256, (380, 1400, 620), np.uint32)` for instance, [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49368179/364696) gets a greater improvement (6.1s down to 1.47s, a reduction of more than 75%).

Comment: @Shawn, interesting.  Can you edit the question to provide more details on how the arrays are generated and any patterns in the data they contain?  For instance if the integers are all non-negative that would open up further possible optimizations.

Answer (score 3):

As [mentioned by daniel451](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49367278/any-way-to-speed-up-numpy-cumsum#comment85735538_49367278), `numpy` isn't parallelizing the `cumsum` operation, so you can parallelize it explicitly to gain at least a little performance.

For example, using `multiprocessing.dummy` (a thread-backed copy of the `multiprocessing` API), you could do:

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
from itertools import repeat

forcing = np.random.rand(380*1400*620).reshape((380,1400,620))

# Make an output array of matching size, that can be populated piecemeal
# in each thread
forceres = np.zeros_like(forcing)

# Compute cumsum in parallel over second dimension
with Pool() as pool:
    # Use module function with np.rollaxis to avoid need to define
    # worker to do slicing
    pool.starmap(np.cumsum, zip(np.rollaxis(forcing, 1), repeat(0), repeat(None), np.rollaxis(forceres, 1)))
```

I tested this with `ipython3`'s `%time`/`%%time` magic on an eight core machine, and found it reduced runtime vs. the original code by almost 70%, from 5.49 seconds to 1.73 seconds; your machine is clearly faster, so if the same speed up occurs on your machine I'd expect it to take ~0.66 seconds.

My comparison was:

```
>>> %%time
... forcesres = np.zeros_like(forcing)
... with Pool() as pool:
...     pool.starmap(np.cumsum, zip(np.rollaxis(forcing, 1), repeat(0), repeat(None), np.rollaxis(forceres, 1)))
CPU times: user 10 s, sys: 213 ms, total: 10.2 s
Wall time: 1.73 s
```

vs.

```
>>> %time forcing.cumsum(axis=0); None  # ; None avoids output
CPU times: user 5.27 s, sys: 218 ms, total: 5.49 s
Wall time: 5.49 s
```

Comment: I will note, on my system, the timings for the `forceres = np.zeros_like(forcing)` is not consistent, presumably in this case due to memory issues (it has to make the new array before releasing the old `forceres`, and I'm operating near my RAM limit). In the bad cases, timing `forcing = np.zeros_like(forcing)` shows a system cost of over two seconds. Regardless, allocating and populating 2.5 GB of RAM is going to have a cost. If you can keep the `forceres` array around for reuse, you could shave the timings by ~20% just by reusing it to avoid the allocation/deallocation overhead.